# Formatting percentages with printf

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Taxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.printf("Enter the employees first name: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String fName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Enter the employees last name: ");

        String lName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Enter the hours worked for the week: ");

        double hours = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("Enter the hourly pay rate: ");

        double pay = input.nextDouble();

        double gross = hours * pay;

        System.out.printf("Enter the federal tax withholding: ");

        double fed = input.nextDouble();
        double fTax = gross * fed;

        System.out.printf("Enter the state tax withholding: ");

        double state = input.nextDouble();
        double sTax = gross * state;

        double Ttax = sTax + fTax;

        double net = gross - Ttax;



        System.out.printf(
                "Employee Name:%s %s\n\nHours Worked:%s hours\n\nPay Rate:$%.2f\n\nGross pay:$%.2f\n\nDeductions: \n\n\tFederal Withholding:(%.2f%%)$%.2f \n\n"
                        + "\tState Withholding:(%.2f%%)$%.2f\n\n\tTotal Witholding:$%.2f\n\nNet Pay:$%.2f",
                fName, lName, hours, pay, gross, fed, fTax, state, sTax, Ttax, net);

        input.close();
    }
}
```

I need to declare two more variables to get the Federal and State tax withholdings to show as a percent.

Example They show as (00.20%) I need them to return as a whole percent like (20.00%)

I've tried declaring new variable at the bottom such as:

```
statewit = sTax * 100;
fedwit = fTax * 100;
```

to get the percents to return as I want but it tends to add that total to the net at the end.

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks!

Comment: java !== javascript :-(

Comment: If so, post an answer and mark it as a valid so the people with the same trouble could benefit from Your experience!

Comment: if you wont use percent you need somewhere in your code use 100 (%), but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 double percent=12.34;
 System.out.printf("%.2f%%", percent);
 // or in different convention "percent as number *100" 
 System.out.printf("%.2f%%", percent*100.0);
```

EDIT: Your Question can be divided in two:

1. Convention in which numbers are used (normal or percent scaled *100)
2. Real formatting to String

BTW Your code is long and has very little to FORMATTING.

Java has no special type for percent values. Types: double, BigDecimal can be used with his behaviour, or integer types too, if programmer keep integer convention

EDIT: thanks  Costis Aivalis , comma corrected :)

Comment: Add a comma between the format string and the variable: System.out.printf("%.2f%%", percent);